# Wierd delay in retrieving dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a loading screen plugin. The scenario is that i am doing page navigation using ajax loading. So before loading a page using ajax, i would show an loading screen using the code `$('body).loadingMask('show')` and once the page is loaded completely loaded, i would remove the loading screen using the code `$('body').loadingMask('hide)`.

The problem is that, there is some delay in retrieving the target dom element inside the plugin.

This is the general structure of the code

```
$('body').loadingMask('show');
$.ajax({
url : 'views/next.html',
    async : false,
success : function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
$('body').append(content);
},
error : function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
throw "Unable to load template. Please check the path and name of the template"
}
});
$('body').loadingMask('hide');
```

The problem is that , inside the show function of the loadingMask plugin, There is a delay in retrieving the target dom element(i.e body) . So pratically, the code `$('body).loadingMask('show')` runs only after the ajax page is finished loading.

In order to make it work , i have added a time delay. Which seems to work fine.

This is the modified code

```
$('body').loadingMask('show');
setTimeout(function(){
$.ajax({
url : 'views/next.html',
    async : false,
success : function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
$('body').append(content);
},
error : function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
throw "Unable to load template. Please check the path and name of the template"
}
});
},500);
$('body').loadingMask('hide');
```

Now i can see the loading screen, while the page loads.

Comment: does this happen to all browsers or just the one you're using?  If you're only using one, which browser is it?

Comment: `async : false` is probably what's doing it. (Though I've had a problem in the past with IE where even with `async : true` it wouldn't show a loading splash screen unless I used a timeout.)

Comment: actually it happens in all browsers. I am making an webapp, this problem is there even in ipad browsers.

Comment: but is there a way, to force the browser to run $('body').loadingMask('show'); command, before it starts loading the next page in ajax. Its kinda weird that, even though the code comes before ajax loading code, the show method plugin is completely run only after the ajax is finished loading. Because, there is delay in retrieving the dom element inside the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `async:false` you can call your plugin withing the ajax success, right after the content gets added.

`async:false` is deprecated and often leads to unforeseen problems

```
$('body').loadingMask('show');
$.ajax({
    url: 'views/next.html',
    success: function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('body').append(content).loadingMask('hide');
    },
    error: function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           /* likely need to remove maske here and add something to content to advise user*/
        throw "Unable to load template. Please check the path and name of the template"
    }
});
```

Comment: Good solution , i tried and it seem to work well. But is there anyway i could do without having to make the request async.

Comment: the first `A` in AJAX is for `asynch`. You can also use `$.ajaxStart()` for a global ajax event handler http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ to call the `show` if you are making numerous requests and need tthe mask

Comment: I get the point. I think it would be better to show loadingmask automatically when ever an ajax request is sent and hide it when ajax request is completed. How can i do that using the ajax events

Comment: numerous methods and examples in the API...  read up on them  http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: will this work$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $(this).loadingMask('show');
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $(this).loadingMask('hide');
 });